# trying to neaten up HW code using arrays and loops (already graded, looking to go further)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a code that has 10 variables and 10 functions. each function retrieves one of the variables and display's the variable on an html page when a button is clicked. Using JavaScript, I was looking for a way to store the variables in an array and then have a for loop cycle through to find which button is clicked and retrieve the proper answer.

I'am new to JavaScript however I believe an array is as simple as

```
var name = ["var0","var1","var2"...];
```

The original code I have is

```
var ans0= "echo";
var ans1= "candle";
var ans2= "map";
var ans3= "the letter r";
function answer0(){
    document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML=ans1;
}
function answer1(){
    document.getElementById("question2").innerHTML=ans2;
}
function answer2(){
    document.getElementById("question3").innerHTML=ans3;
}
function answer3(){
    document.getElementById("question4").innerHTML=ans4;
}
```

Basically I know this can work I just need some guidance as to syntax and logic.

The other bit of information that may help is my html code:

```
<div class="questions">
                <p class="question">1. I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have nobody, but come alive with wind. What am I?</p><!-- echo -->
                <div class="answer-btn">
                    <input type="button" class="get" value="Answer" onclick="answer(0);">           
                </div><!--/.answer-btn -->          
                <span class="the-answer" id="question1"></span>     
            </div><!--/.questions -->
```

These lines of code are also repeated over and over and i would be nice to only have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store your answers in separate variables.
You can use object to store your answers corresponding to your question. But for your case and simplicity, you can try this:

```
var answers = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'etc'];

function printAnswer(questionNumber) {
  document.getElementById('question'+questionNumber).innerHTML = answers[questionNumber-1];
}
```

Expecting printAnswer(1) to be called for first question.

Comment: downvote. A classic "off by 1"  error. If not in fact, in readability at least. The OP's code does start w/ `var0` so *maybe* this answer will work. But it would not pass a code review IMHO.

Comment: Added clarification. Maybe it'll help

Comment: The key for me is mapping `['answer1', ...]` to `answers[questionNumber-1]` in my widdle bwain. I would: for all internal code everything be zero-based. For user output then we can display starting w/ "1".  The numbering offset is in the clearly-user-facing text/output only, and it is clearly in the spot where we transition from internal processing to user output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy, add a parameter to your function:

```
function answer(n) {
  document.getElementById("question" + n).innerHTML= allAnswers [n]
}
```

Where `allAnswers` would be

```
var allAnswers = ["echo","candle","map","the letter r"]
```

Then, you either add a listener in your HTML for each button respectively like:

```
 <button class="answer_btn" onclick="answer(0)"></button>
 <button class="answer_btn" onclick="answer(1)"></button>
 ....
```

or, as you suggested, you could loop through the buttons and add the listeners:

```
  var  buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_btn")
  for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  button.item(i).addEventListener('click', function()  {
    answer(i)
  })
}
```

Keep in mind that you really need to use `let` here because else, you will have to use a trick to bound `i` to another scope:

```
  var  buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_btn")
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    button.item(i).addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() { answer(i) }
    }(i)))
  }
```

**Edit:** To answer your second question (how to make your HTML simpler, without repetitions), you could use javascript to generate the dom. However, this doesn't mean that your final HTML (the generated one) will be any simpler, but the code will look simpler and (possibly) easier to read. First, you create your container for all the questions and answers:

```
<div id="questions_container"></div>
```

In javascript, we will reference it and create another array to store all questions.

```
var questionsDiv = document.getElementById("questions_container")
var questionsText = ["1. ...... ?", "2. ........ ?", ...]
```

Then, looping through the questions, we will add them to the DOM:

```
for(var q in questionsText) {
   questionsDiv.innerHTML += 
   '<p class="question">' + questionsText[q] + '</p>\
      <div class="answer-btn">\
         <input type="button" class="get" value="Answer" onclick="answer(' + q + ');"> \          
      </div>\
      <span class="the-answer" id="question' + (q+1) + ' </span>'
}
```

Hope I helped you!

Comment: I think I understand your logic and it all makes sense however there is a break in my code somewhere. I posted the first question of my HTML code. First and foremost I'd love if you could catch where I was going wrong and second. If there is a way to make it so that I don't have to repeat the same code for each new question in the HTML bit that would be grand